# In Android how I do the hear beat animation?

Tags: java, android, xml

In my Android app My requirement is 
a "heart" will beat [As like the picture....](http://www.ecigarettedirect.co.uk/ashtray-blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Heart.gif)
So I have downloaded a heart pic..make the pic background as transparent..
and store it into my **drawable** folder..
and My code is:-- 
**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

</LinearLayout>

and in **res/anim** I have **scale.xml** 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:duration="1000"
  android:fromXScale="0.5"
  android:fromYScale="0.5"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:repeatCount="infinite"
  android:repeatMode="reverse"
  android:toXScale="1.5"
  android:toYScale="1.5" />
```

and **MainActivity.java** is:--

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    i.startAnimation(a);
    }
    }
```

So,the its running..but not like that as shown in my pic..how Can I achieve my requirement??

Comment: Making the image fade and and fade out wont make it beat anything like the image you linked to?

Comment: But this is not fade and fade out..BTW how can I achieve that?